# Make a consensus tree from several tree using Bio.phylo

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, phylogeny

I'm interested in 4 housekeeping genes in enterobacter bacteria genome's.

So I have my housekeeping genes, I made a blast on NR and download the aligned sequences.

I made phylogenetic trees using MEGA7 software with Maximum Likehood method. Boostrap method was performed with 200 iterations.

I export my trees as newick files.

So now, I have 4 trees for my 4 housekeeping genes. I want to create a consensus tree of my 4 trees.

Personally I tried to use consensus tree from Bio.Phylo (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Phylo.Consensus-module.html#strict_consensus) (http://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo).
I choose the majority_consensus function and it's work pretty well. But I have an issue.

My "script" is like that :

```
import os

import sys

from Bio import Phylo

from Bio.Phylo.Consensus import *

fichier=sys.argv[1]

fichier2=sys.argv[2]

fichier3=sys.argv[3]

fichier4=sys.argv[4]

tree1=Phylo.read(fichier, 'newick')

tree2=Phylo.read(fichier2, 'newick')

tree3=Phylo.read(fichier3, 'newick')

tree4=Phylo.read(fichier4, 'newick')

trees=tree1,tree2,tree3,tree4

majority_tree = majority_consensus(trees, 0.5)

Phylo.draw(majority_tree)
```

The problem is that the consensus tree is dependant on the order.
I had different result for exemple when I `try trees = tree1,tree2,tree3,tree4` and `trees = tree2,tree4,tree1,tree3`

Does someone know another software to make consensus tree from newick files?

And I need help with `Bio.Phylo`. If someone know more about this package it will be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Your English is clear, but your question is not. It seems to be about biology and the specifics of the tree-building algorithm you are intending to use. Maybe your question would be more suited for the [biology stack exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com/).
However, if your question actually is about programming you should rephrase it: Skip the details about stats and biology. Provide an example that can be reproduced by other (we lack your files for instance). State clearly the nature of your programming problem. This will increase your chance of getting answers.

Comment: Thanks. 
BioGeek understood well my problem. It's about Biology but it's an informatic problem. 

Thanks you for your response :)

Comment: I am happy you got a satisfying answer :-)
I understand your question better now that I read the answer and saw an illustration of the Newick format.

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn't post your newick files, let's try to reproduce your problem so that we have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows that  consensus tree is dependant on the order.

We start with the following three trees:

[image: three trees]

These are represented as follows in newick format:

```
newicks = {1: '((A,B,C),(D,(E,F)))',
           2: '(((A,B),C),(D,(E,F)))',
           3: '((A,B,C),(E,(D,F)))'}
```

Now we try all possible permutation of these three trees, create the consensus tree and see if they are all the same:

```
from io import StringIO
from Bio import Phylo
from Bio.Phylo.Consensus import majority_consensus
from itertools import permutations

def read_newick(treedata):
    handle = StringIO(treedata)
    return Phylo.read(handle, "newick")

for keys in permutations(newicks.keys()):
    trees = [read_newick(newicks[key]) for key in keys]
    majority_tree = majority_consensus(trees, 0.5)
    print('majority consensus for order: {}'.format(keys))
    Phylo.draw_ascii(majority_tree)
```

Result:

```
majority consensus for order: (1, 2, 3)
                           ________________________ A
                          |
  ________________________|________________________ B
 |                        |
_|                        |________________________ C
 |
 |                         ________________________ D
 |________________________|
                          |                         ________________________ E
                          |________________________|
                                                   |________________________ F

majority consensus for order: (1, 3, 2)
                           ________________________ A
                          |
  ________________________|________________________ B
 |                        |
_|                        |________________________ C
 |
 |                         ________________________ D
 |________________________|
                          |                         ________________________ E
                          |________________________|
                                                   |________________________ F

majority consensus for order: (2, 1, 3)
                           ________________________ A
                          |
  ________________________|________________________ B
 |                        |
_|                        |________________________ C
 |
 |                         ________________________ D
 |________________________|
                          |                         ________________________ E
                          |________________________|
                                                   |________________________ F

majority consensus for order: (2, 3, 1)
                           ________________________ A
                          |
  ________________________|________________________ B
 |                        |
_|                        |________________________ C
 |
 |                         ________________________ D
 |________________________|
                          |                         ________________________ E
                          |________________________|
                                                   |________________________ F

majority consensus for order: (3, 1, 2)
                           ________________________ A
                          |
  ________________________|________________________ B
 |                        |
_|                        |________________________ C
 |
 |                         ________________________ E
 |________________________|
                          |                         ________________________ D
                          |________________________|
                                                   |________________________ F

majority consensus for order: (3, 2, 1)
                           ________________________ A
                          |
  ________________________|________________________ B
 |                        |
_|                        |________________________ C
 |
 |                         ________________________ E
 |________________________|
                          |                         ________________________ D
                          |________________________|
                                                   |________________________ F
```

So indeed, the last two consensus trees are different from the first four consensus trees.

To understand why that happens, we look at the source code for [majority_consensus()](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Phylo.Consensus-pysrc.html). There we see that the first step is to create the root clade. The order for the terminal clades is determined by the first tree that is provided.

So for `(tree1, tree2, tree3)`, the first provided tree is `tree1` and the root clade is `ABCDEF`. But for `(tree3, tree2, tree1)` the first tree provided is `tree3` and the root clade becomes `ABC`**`ED`**`F`.

So, this is a limitation of the algorithm itself and any implementation of majority consensus will give you a different order dependent on the first provided tree.

Comment: Thanks you. Your exemple is very clear and you really well understood my problem.
Sorry to doesn't post my data, it's a kind of a big tree and I don't know how I can post it. But thanks to you. You gave a great exemple.

So I can't do nothing for this. Because I'm waiting to have the same consensus tree no matter the order of input files.

Thanks you very much for you response :)

Comment: I'm surprised that the majority rule depends on input order. If this is the case with biopyton, this may be that the algorithm is wrong. The result should contain clade (E, F) since it is present in 2/3 of the trees.